# Error: Unable to find a match phpmyadmin when i try to install phpmyadmin on centos

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

```
[root@vmi329080 ~]# sudo yum install phpmyadmin
Last metadata expiration check: 0:57:18 ago on Sun 05 Jan 2020 01:05:52 PM CET.
No match for argument: phpmyadmin
Error: Unable to find a match
```

This is what i get when i install phpmyadmin ..

Comment: There is no `phpmyadmin` package available in the core CentOS repositories. You can find a package in the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: And why people downvoted the question without bothering to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install epel repository to be accessible by yum

```
rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y update
yum -y install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: I give this error "No match for argument: phpmyadmin
Error: Unable to find a match: phpmyadmin" when I use "yum -y install phpmyadmin".

Comment: it means epel repository not installed

Comment: I had installed the epel repository completely

Answer (score 1):

Despite trying all the solutions mentioned above, none of them worked for me. However, I was able to find a solution that worked after conducting further research.

In case any of the PHP stream from the "remi-modular" repository are enabled, it is possible to install phpMyAdmin from the "remi" non-modular repository.

```
# dnf module enable php:remi-7.4 
# dnf --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
```