# Unable to install phpmyadmin with yum in centos 8

Tags: phpmyadmin, yum, centos8, epel

I want to install phpmyadmin on my centos 8 vps. I even installed epel-release and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601769/13319585) but it keeps saying:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:10:30 ago on Thu 04 Mar 2021 05:42:27 PM IST.
No match for argument: phpMyAdmin
Error: Unable to find a match: phpMyAdmin
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confident that phpMyAdmin is not included in the EPEL package repository.

I'm also a huge fan of Remi's work to maintain the [Remi package repository](https://rpms.remirepo.net/). There you can find a very recent phpMyAdmin along with all the dependencies that are very easy to install.

Comment: Indeed, while phpMyAdmin was in EPEL-7 (an old version) it is not in EPEL-8 because of Fedora infrastructure not supporting modules

Comment: Strangely enough, EPEL-9 has phpmyadmin https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/9/Everything/x86_64/Packages/p/phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-1.el9.noarch.rpm too, just not EPEL-8.